# Merge donut with its hole

Tags: qgis, polygon, donut-polygons

I have a layer with polygons in QGIS. The one selected on the bottom has a hole in it, the hole is also a shape. So I have the donut and his hole. How can I merge these two polygons?

EDIT: I didn't emphasise this but I want to utilise the solution for my whole dataset of around 7 million polygons.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If both features have a common attribute, you can [Dissolve](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdissolve) the layer defining the field of the common attribute.

---

If they don't have a common attribute, you can delete all holes with the [Delete Holes](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#qgisdeleteholes) tool.
The output is a *Cleaned* layer with the same features than the input, but just the exterior ring of their geometries.

This layer will have also the buildings features.
If you want to remove them, you will need to detect them first:

Run the [Execute SQL](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#qgisexecutesql) tool with the following SQL query:

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM "Cleaned" a 
INNER JOIN "Cleaned" b 
ON (
  ST_Intersects(a.geometry, b.geometry) 
  AND 
  ST_Relate(a.geometry, b.geometry, 'TFFTFFTTT')
)
```

That query will evaluate each feature of the *Cleaned* layer against each other, and extracting just those that are *strictly contained <sup>[1]</sup>* into another one.

The output is a *SQL Output* layer with the houses features.

Then, [Select by Location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html#qgisselectbylocation), from the *Cleaned* layer, those features that are equal to *SQL Output* layer features:

[image: 2]

Once selected, remove them and export the *Cleaned* layer to a file.

---

*<sup>[1]</sup>*  Within but the boundaries don't touch. For more information, look at the [Dimensionally Extended nine-Intersection Model (DE-9IM) Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DE-9IM)

Comment: This worked! I tested it on a small subset and I could select the holes and delete them. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the edit mode is enabled. If you select both polygons you can merge them together. You find the merge option by clicking on edit in the toolbar. Then you have to chose what happens to the attributes of the polygons. As soon as you verify everything with "Ok" it merges both polygons.

Comment: Yes, indeed this would work, I haven't described my question in detail but I need it to be scalable. I created an EDIT. Still thanks though.